# Playa data not displaying

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic

I have recently come across an issue on a site I'm working on. The problem is that a Playa field doesn't seem to be displaying a related entry title. Normally I have no issue whatsoever with Playa tags so this has me stumped.

Here is the opening channel tag

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="courses" dynamic="on" limit="8" disable="member_data"
    status="not closed"
    paginate="bottom" paginate_base="{language_prefix}/courses/category/{segment_3}"}
```

This channel contains

- An image (file field)
- Title
- Category (using the `{categories}` tag)
- A short abstract (text area)

and also a related venue field (using Playa) coded as the following

```
{course_related_venue disable="member_data"}{title}1{/course_related_venue}
```

This is followed by pagination and then the closing `{/exp:channel:entries}`.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing that would cause the Playa field data to not display. It seems that anything inside the Playa tag just isn't being recognized, even if I hardcode something inside there.

Can someone maybe shed some light on this?

*and in case it helps, this is on a category page so has a url of /courses/category/C6/

@Lisa Wess: additional information you requested

### **Versions**

EE v2.5.2
Playa v4.1.0.3

### **Template Code**

```
{embed="includes/_head" title="{general_custom_homepage_title}" hide_site_title="y" body="courses"}

<header class="head-container course detail">

<div class="container">
      <img class="courses-for-you" src="/assets/images/courses/courses-course.png">


        {exp:aj_lang:get_text word="courses"}




{exp:channel:category_heading dynamic="on" channel="courses"}<h4>{exp:aj_lang:get_text word="Course Category"}:  {if language_prefix=="/en"}{category_name}{if:else}{course_category_name{language_suffix}}{/if}</h4>
{/exp:channel:category_heading} 

</div><!--/container-->
</header><!--/head-container-->
<br class="visible-phone"/>
<div class="container">    
<div class="row">
<div class="span4">


          <p class="label">{exp:aj_lang:get_text word="Course Category"}</p>
        <ul class="category-spanned">
        {exp:channel:categories style="linear" category_group="3"}


              <li><a href="{path={language_prefix}/courses/category}"> {if language_prefix=="/en"}{category_name}{if:else}{course_category_name{language_suffix}}{/if}</a></li>


             {/exp:channel:categories}
         </ul>





</div><!--/spnn4-->

<div class="span8">  



<p class="label">{exp:channel:category_heading dynamic="on" channel="courses"} {if language_prefix=="/en"}{category_name}{if:else}{course_category_name{language_suffix}}{/if}{/exp:channel:category_heading} {exp:aj_lang:get_text word="Courses"}</p>

{exp:channel:entries channel="courses" dynamic="on" limit="8" disable="member_data" status="not closed" paginate="bottom" paginate_base="{language_prefix}/courses/category/{segment_3}"} 

<div class="row"><!--nested row open-->


<div class="span1">
{if course_image}
      {course_image}
      <span class="course-image">{exp:imgsizer:size src="{url}" width="70" height="70"}</span>
      {/course_image}
      {if:else}
       <span class="course-image">{exp:imgsizer:size src="/assets/images/courses/placeholder-course.jpg" width="70" height="70"}</span>
{/if}
</div><!--/span1-->

<div class="span7">


      <h2 class="title"><a class="course" href="{language_prefix}/courses/{url_title}">{title}</a></h2>


          <p class="no-font"><small>{exp:aj_lang:get_text word="Category"}:{categories}  {if language_prefix=="/en"}{category_name}{if:else}{course_category_name{language_suffix}}{/if}{/categories}</small></p>
          <p class="no-font"><small>{exp:aj_lang:get_text word="Venue"}: {course_related_venue}{title}{/course_related_venue} </small></p>

          <p>{if course_abstract{language_suffix}}{course_abstract{language_suffix}}
          {if:else}{exp:aj_lang:get_text word="Currently awaiting more information"}{/if}
          </p>
          <br/>
<ul>

</ul>
          <p><a class="button course shadow" href="{language_prefix}/courses/{url_title}">{exp:aj_lang:get_text word="More about this course"} &raquo;</a></p>

          {if no_results}
           <p>{exp:aj_lang:get_text word="Currently no courses in this category"}</p>
          {/if}





</div><!--/span7-->

</div><!--/nested-row--><hr/>


{paginate}
 {pagination_links}<div class="centered block">
        <ul class="paginate centered">


                {previous_page}
                        <li class="float-left"><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-previous">Previous&nbsp;</a></li>
                {/previous_page}

                {page}
                        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number} {if current_page}active{/if}">{pagination_page_number}&nbsp;//&nbsp; </a></li>
                {/page}

                {next_page}
                        <li class="float-right"><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-next">Next</a></li>
                {/next_page}


        </ul></div>
{/pagination_links}
    {/paginate}




{/exp:channel:entries}
</div><!--/spnn8-->
</div><!--/row-->

</div><!--/container-->
<hr class="course">

{embed="includes/_foot"}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this here!  Before we go further, I'd recommend updating at least Playa to 4.3.3, and EE to 2.5.5 if you're up for that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Can I ask you to create a totally new template. Put **nothing** but this in it:

```
 {exp:channel:entries channel="courses" dynamic="on" limit="8" disable="member_data" status="not closed"} 
<h1>{title}</h1>
    {course_related_venue}<strong>course_related_venue:</strong> {title}{/course_related_venue}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Make sure you're pulling up an entry on that template that has at least one child.  Do you get any data out of that?

Thanks!